# Should I use my package name for KMM SqlDelight config?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, sqldelight

I am following this [guide](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Networking%20and%20Data%20Storage%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatfrom%20Mobile/05_Configuring_SQLDelight_an_implementing_cache) and in the first section of this step I have to do the following:

```
 sqldelight {
    database("AppDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.jetbrains.handson.kmm.shared.cache"
    }
}
```

Question is, should I use `.handson.` or `.myPackageName.` and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guide from [your link](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Networking%20and%20Data%20Storage%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatfrom%20Mobile/05_Configuring_SQLDelight_an_implementing_cache) says

> The `packageName` parameter specifies the package name for the generated Kotlin sources.

As with any kotlin file, you can specify any package name you want, but a good practice is to put all the files in the same module under the module package.

Let's say your module has the package name `com.app.modules.shared`. You can use the same package name for the generated database or some sub-path such as `com.app.modules.shared.database`.